# Prioritizing newer answers over older or obsolete ones

Tags: discussion, search

I've been searching for answer to questions about Android, which as a platform is only 7 years old.  It has changed drastically over that time, and answers to questions that were posed 3 or 5 years ago are out of date.  In some cases the answers are inappropriate or just wrong for current developers.

Unlike some similar questions here, I'm not suggesting downvoting or removing these questions.  They were likely true and helpful at the time and I believe should be preserved.  What I'm loking for here has to do with the search functionality.

I wonder if there's a way to de-emphasize older questions during a search, to steer people towards newer solutions. I've only been using SO for a couple of years, but it's become harder to find a valuable answer as older, obsolete answers pile up.  It would be useful to have the most relevant answers be prioritized.

I also want to say that this is not the same as sorting by date - relevance is still the most important factor, but all things considered, a newer answer may be more relevant, especially in certain subjects.

Comment: Sorry to say this, but using google with a custom date range and site:stackoverflow.com is probably your best bet.

Comment: You could filter by date, as in `[android] is:q created:2y` to get questions asked in the last 2 years. You can also use `lastactive:` to get an activity (edit/answer) filter. [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)